# Allowing all users to create a repo in TFS-GIT

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

I have set up a TFS project in VSO using git for source control.  Is there a way I can give all members of that project the ability to create a git repository?  The only way I see is to make everyone an administrator, but I don't necessarily want them to be able to manage members and other settings... just create new repos.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They must be administrator at Version Control level, no need to be Team nor Project Administrators.

Let me explain what I did for a team of mine.

- I created a `Git Admins` TFS Group (*YourProjectUrl*`/_admin/_security` page i.e. **Security** tab)
- Then in the **Version Control** tab (i.e. the *YourProjectUrl*`/_admin/_versioncontrol` page) with the root node selected, add the `Git Admins` TFS Group
- Give the `Git Admins` TFS Group allow `Administer`
- Avoid giving **Rewrite and destroy history (force push)** permission except for Project or better Server administrator as it is really dangerous